# When running a script I get "divide by zero” in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run a script in SQL in which I am dividing but I am getting the error "Divide by zero error encountered"

I tried to add in NULLIF which was suggested in an old post I read but this didnt help it.

```
SELECT SUM([SE Gross]) AS [Donors Gross],
       ROUND((SUM([Cancelled]) * 100) / NULLIF(SUM([SE Gross]), 2), 0),
       SUM([Venue Cost]),
       SUM([Accom/Expenses]),
       ROUND(SUM([SE Gross]) / NULLIF(SUM([fundraising days]), 2), 0) AS Column1,
       ROUND(SUM([Venue Cost]) / NULLIF(SUM([SE Gross]), 2), 0) AS Column2,
       ROUND(SUM([Venue Cost] + [Accom/Expenses]) / NULLIF(SUM([SE Gross]), 2), 0) AS column3,
       ROUND(SUM([Venue Cost] + [Accom/Expenses]) / NULLIF(SUM([donor net COUNT]), 2), 0) AS column4
FROM dbo.TEST1;
```

The result I currently get is: Divide by zero error encountered.

Comment: I think you probably wanted ISNULL, not NULLIF. Did you actually go and read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to understand what that function does?? Don't blindly copy code from the internet without understanding at least the basic idea of it. Since search engines are so powerful and documentation and examples are so plentiful these days, there's usually very little excuse for not doing at least a bit of simple research, it only takes a few seconds

Comment: I tagged your question `sql-server`, based on the column delimiters and the use of nullif(). If I was wrong about that, you need to fix your tags.

Comment: There is a division error, so (as a debug step) split the two components of that division into separate columns and inspect for 0's

Comment: Ps. If the data in your field is actually just 0, then ISNULL won't help you either....maybe a CASE statement might be better. You didn't show us any sample data, so we can't be sure precisely what situation is occurring

Comment: Looks like you systematically swapped the arguments to `ROUND` and `NULLIF`. You're currently using `NULLIF(SUM([SE Gross]), 2)`, which will turn the result into `NULL` if `SUM([SE Gross])` is exactly equal to 2. You want `NULLIF(SUM([SE Gross]), 0)` (and round to 2 digits, presumably).

Comment: @ADyson I'm sure op did *not* want to use `isnull`. Do you understand what `nullif` is supposed to achieve here? There's no need to admonish op quite so aggressively (especially when you apparently don't understand what they are trying to achieve).

Comment: @HoneyBadger Yes I do know what it does - I posted the link to the docs, if you recall. Let's say `SUM([SE Gross]` is `0`. `NULLIF(SUM([SE Gross]), 2)` would then return `0`. So there's still a divide-by error. Doesn't really solve the problem, does it? If `SUM([SE Gross]` is `2`, then the `NULLIF` would return `NULL`...and while dividing by `NULL` won't error, that doesn't strike me as a particularly useful outcome. So it's pretty unclear to me what OP was trying to do by using it, or what they thought it would do, but you seem to have an idea? It would be useful to hear it.

Comment: @HoneyBadger P.S. I did later clarify my initial suggestion about ISNULL...it might or might not be useful depending on the circumstances.

Comment: @ADyson, I didn't doubt you know what it does, I doubted you realized what OP was trying to use it for. Yes, OP clearly used `ifnull` wrong. Jeroen Mostert identified the likely error, which made it look like a typographical error (arguments in wrong place/function). No offence intended, I just thought you were pushing for research a bit too hard, when the error was just an argument in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks all, I know it was a bit of an open question and that I could have investigated a bit more. But this is not my forte unfortunatley and I tried what I could. :)

Comment: @HoneyBadger understood, no offence taken. Sorry if you thought my initial comment was a bit OTT...I just felt that if OP had looked more closely at the docs, and then back at their own code, and unit-tested that function a bit, they might have actually figured out what must be happening. And yes, now I re-read Jeroen's comment that does make some sense. I just didn't really think OP would want `NULL` as the final output, but maybe that's fine for their purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to convert to `NULL` if it's equal to 2. Check this part: `NULLIF(SUM([SE Gross]), 2)`, you have to change `2` to `0` in the following:

```
SELECT SUM([SE Gross]) AS [Donors Gross],
       ROUND((SUM([Cancelled]) * 100) / NULLIF(SUM([SE Gross]), 0), 0),
       SUM([Venue Cost]),
       SUM([Accom/Expenses]),
       ROUND(SUM([SE Gross]) / NULLIF(SUM([fundraising days]), 0), 0) AS Column1,
       ROUND(SUM([Venue Cost]) / NULLIF(SUM([SE Gross]), 0), 0) AS Column2,
       ROUND(SUM([Venue Cost] + [Accom/Expenses]) / NULLIF(SUM([SE Gross]), 0), 0) AS column3,
       ROUND(SUM([Venue Cost] + [Accom/Expenses]) / NULLIF(SUM([donor net COUNT]), 0), 0) AS column4
FROM dbo.TEST1;
```

Also, you could use `CASE` statement to avoid null of entire entry if divider = 0, in the following:

```
CASE WHEN NULLIF(SUM([SE Gross]), 0) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULLIF(SUM([SE Gross]), 0) END
```

Or combine `ISNULL` with `NULLIF` in the following:

```
ISNULL(NULLIF(SUM([SE Gross]), 0), 1)
```

My guess is that you wanted to round up to 2 decimal places so in this case, it should be like this:

```
ROUND((SUM([Cancelled]) * 100) / ISNULL(NULLIF(SUM([SE Gross]), 0), 1), 2)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for understanding and helping me out :)

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas . . . Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

Just to correct my previous response - CASE should be used:

```
SELECT SUM([SE Gross]) AS [Donors Gross],
       CASE WHEN SUM([SE Gross]<>0 THEN ROUND((SUM([Cancelled]) * 100) / NULLIF(SUM([SE Gross]), 2), 0) ELSE 0 END,
       SUM([Venue Cost]),
       SUM([Accom/Expenses]),
       CASE WHEN SUM([fundraising days] <> 0 THEN ROUND(SUM([SE Gross]) / NULLIF(SUM([fundraising days]), 2), 0) ELSE 0 END AS Column1,
       CASE WHEN SUM([SE Gross] <> 0 THEN ROUND(SUM([Venue Cost]) / NULLIF(SUM([SE Gross]), 2), 0) ELSE 0 END AS Column2,
       CASE WHEN SUM([SE Gross] <> 0 THEN ROUND(SUM([Venue Cost] + [Accom/Expenses]) / NULLIF(SUM([SE Gross]), 2), 0) ELSE 0 END AS column3,
       CASE WHEN SUM([donor net COUNT] <> 0 THEN ROUND(SUM([Venue Cost] + [Accom/Expenses]) / NULLIF(SUM([donor net COUNT]), 2), 0) ELSE 0 END AS column4
FROM dbo.TEST1;
```

This should work now :)

You can also remove NULLIFs if needed (I left them since I do not know whether you might need them for different purposes)